# Prove trig identity: $(\sin \theta + 1)(\sin \theta − 1) = −\cos^2 θ$

Tags: trigonometry

This is my attempt:

$(\sin \theta+1)(\sin \theta-1) = \sin\theta^2 - \sin\theta + \sin\theta - 1$

$= \sin^2\theta - 1$

$= -\cos^2\theta$

Is it correct, and can it be improved? Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. Nice work.

Comment: Pretty much as short as it gets.

Comment: It is absolutely correct.

Comment: Similarly,you can simplify $(\cos\theta+1)(\cos\theta-1)$

Comment: Two things - First: You've written $\sin\theta^2$. This should actually (in the context of the question) be $\sin^2\theta$. Second: It is correct, but the step $sinθ^2−sinθ+sinθ−1$ is not required. In fact, you could just use the identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: Perfectly correct. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct.You must be knowing that $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$. Therefore $(sin\theta+1)(sin\theta-1)=sin^2\theta-1=-cos^2\theta$